# Repeat with contents of multiple lists

Tags: applescript

Below is a simplfied version of a script I've been working (and had help with).
and is all working fine.
I'm wanting to develop this so when starting the script it shows dialog box with buttons with that do the below.

Button one Runs Both "Spec1" and "Spec2"

Button Two Runs Both "Spec2" and "Spec3"

Button Three shows a list dialog to select either  "Spec1","Spec2","Spec3" (Like the script already does)

The final script will have a few more specs however this is enough to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

Thanks

```
-- Spec realted file extensions

--Spec 1
set ListSpec1 to {"_0006", "_0007", "_0010", "_0011"}

--Spec 2
set ListSpec2 to {"_0000", "_0001", "_0002", "_0003", "_0004", "_0005"}

--Spec 3
set ListSpec3 to {"_0006"}


-- Obtain user choice of PS action 
set PhotoshopActionList to {"Spec1", "Spec2", "Spec3"}
set ChosenSpec to choose from list PhotoshopActionList with title "Actions       Picker" with prompt "Choose Action?"


-- If user cancels, then terminate the script
if ChosenSpec is false then
error number -128 (* user cancelled *)
else
set ChosenSpec to ChosenSpec's item 1 (* extract choice from list*)
end if

--Set image source folder
set SourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose Base Images:")
set FoldertoReplace to SourceFolder & ChosenSpec as text

--set image save folder
set DestinationFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose Save Location:")
set filelocation to DestinationFolder as text


--Setting Files list
tell application "Finder" to set filesList to files of entire contents of        SourceFolder whose name ends with ".tif"

repeat with CurrentFile in filesList
tell application "Finder"
    set NameF to name of CurrentFile
    set currentFileAlias to (CurrentFile as alias) as text
end tell


-- Canadian Files Lists 
if ChosenSpec is "Spec1" then
    set theListSpecToUse to ListSpec1
else if ChosenSpec is "Spec2" then
    set theListSpecToUse to ListSpec2
else
    set theListSpecToUse to ListSpec3
end if


-- the file name contains a valid pattern, then process the file
if FNameOK(NameF, theListSpecToUse) then

    --open photoshop
    tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2017"
        open alias currentFileAlias

        --Canadain Actions
        if ChosenSpec is "Spec1" then
            do action "Spec1" as text from "Specs"
        else if ChosenSpec is "Spec2" then
            do action "Spec2" as text from "Specs"
        else if ChosenSpec is "Spec3" then
            do action "Spec3" as text from "Specs"
        end if


        --Saving to Format


        -- Canadian Saves
        if ChosenSpec is "Spec1" then
            save current document in filelocation as TIFF with options {class:TIFF save options, image compression:LZW, transparency:true, embed color profile:true}
        else if ChosenSpec is "Spec2" then
            save current document in filelocation as TIFF with options {class:TIFF save options, image compression:LZW, transparency:true, embed color profile:true}
        else
            save current document in filelocation as PNG with options {class:PNG save options, compression:9, interlaced:false} appending no extension with copying
        end if

        --Close Photoshop Document
        close current document without saving

    end tell
end if
end repeat


on FNameOK(Local_Name, LocalList) -- check if the file name contains an   element of the list
set LocalCheck to false
repeat with OneItem in LocalList
    if Local_Name contains OneItem then
        return true
    end if
end repeat
return false
end FNameOK
```

Comment: Not quite understanding your question, but looking through your script quickly, I recommend changing the line under `"--Setting Files list"` to `tell application "Finder" to set filesList to (document files of entire contents of SourceFolder whose name ends with ".tif") as alias list`.  It will be a faster operation and there'll be no need to coerce `CurrentFile` to alias a couple of lines below that, as it will already be of type `alias`.

Comment: Brilliant I will give it a go,

Sorry if i question was unclear. The current script displays as list and then uses the list selection to perform different actions.

As mentioned this is a smaller version of my script but objective is still the same.

Comment: Instead of selecting an option from a list dialog i would like to show a button dialog that loops through items in the list for example

    **Button1* will perform script with **Spec1** then Loop/reapeats with **Spec2** and

    **Button2* will perform script with **Spec2** then Loop/reapeats with **Spec3**

Im just struggling with looping/repeating the entire script

(In the larger script files are saving in different locations so overwriting isn't an issue)

Thanks again for all your help
JdG

Comment: So, boiling this problem down, it sounds like we can forget what your script goes on to do as it's largely irrelevant to your specific issue which, if I'm understanding you correctly, is wanting to know how to create a dialog with three buttons.  Is that right ?  i.e. Instead of presenting the user with a list of three options, you wish to present a dialog with three buttons, yes ?

Comment: Yes, I’m confident in creating a three button dialog however the bit I’m really struggling with is getting the button to return as if multiple list selections have been made and then looping through the script for these, hope this makes sense. Thanks again for taking the time to respond.